# How to load files in memory & read them from there rather hitting disk

Tags: java, apache-fop

I have a fop method which take the absolute file paths to read them from the disk. But I need to read those same files multiple times, then I want skip to read the same files every time from disk. So I need help to implement the solution where I will pass the path of the files in memory, if file is in memory then it will be read from there, else it will first be loaded in memory then read from memory, to make the whole process faster. As currently code is looking files in disk every time, which is making the execution lot slower.

Comment: The OS has a filesystem cache, so if you have a performance problem it is very unlikely that "the files not being in memory" is the problem. This, or your files are _very_ large.

Comment: Agree, files must be in memory in the method needs the absolute path of the file to be read, so currently I am passing that path pointing to disk. But I want, if the file is not in memory then load it first in memory then method reads that file from memory but not from disk, but it must feel like it is reading that from disk.

Answer (score 2):

Keep a `Map` of file references to file contents.  When you need to access a file, look in your `Map`.  If the file has an entry, use the mapped contents.  Otherwise, load the file as you would normally, but add the file reference and contents to the `Map`.  Something like this:

```
Map<Path, byte[]> fileContentMap = new HashMap<>();    
Path filePath = Paths.get("some/path/to/a/file");
byte[] fileContents;
if(fileContentMap.containsKey(filePath)){
  fileContents = fileContentMap.get(filePath);
}else{
  fileContents = Files.readAllBytes(filePath);
  fileContentMap.put(filePath, fileContents); 
}
//use fileContents however you need
```

Comment: Thanks, it could have been the solution if I am reading byte array. But here, I don't know about how that method is working on files as it takes just the absolute path of the file. And currently I am passing the absolute path pointing to disk, but to increase the performance, I want to make that method to get the file from memory first, before looking on disk. So requested for some solution to achieve such.